# Cannot center element in the middle of the div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this little arrow that i want to put right in the middle of my div to make it look like a carousel/slideshow control, like a next button or a previous button. I cannot seem to make it work, with or without bootstrap.

What am i missing? It is part of a bigger structure, and maybe that's why?

Here is the Html:

```css
.III{
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    position:relative;
 }
.semn{
    background-color: blue;
    height:90px;
    width:90px;
    border-radius:90px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: center; 
}
.sagetica{
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="III container-fluid col-md-12">
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row align-items-center align-self-center ">  
          <div class="stanga col-md-2 text-center ">
             <div class="semn">
              <p class='sagetica'> &lt; </p>
             </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox to solve this issue. Just apply display flex property to circular div and align items centrally.

```
    .semn{
background-color: blue;
height:90px;
width:90px;
border-radius:90px;
margin:0 auto;
display: flex;
align-items: center; 
text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Element with `.semn` class has `display: inline-block;` property. Therefore `text-align: center` property doesn`t work. Try to delete it.

Result

```css
.III {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.semn {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  text-align: center;
}

.sagetica {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="III container-fluid col-md-12">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-center align-self-center ">
        <div class="stanga col-md-2 text-center ">
          <div class="semn">
            <p class='sagetica'>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with bootstrap 4

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <p class="mx-auto d-block "> > </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am using bootstrap 4 and when i tried this method it didnt work

Comment: Try 
<code>
       <div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> > </div>

    </div>
</code>
It's BS4